# Add timer to 1 of these files in this script

Tags: python, bash, shell, file, time

I have 2 files that print on the same line at the same time. I wanted to add time.sleep() to 1 of the textfiles. I wanted to delay the time that 1 textfile prints with the other 1 in this script. I wanted to have the files to create new lines instead of printing the same combinations when they both print. Where to add the time.sleep()?

```
from itertools import izip_longest
import time

with open("file1") as textfile1, open("file2") as textfile2:
for x, y in izip_longest(textfile1, textfile2, fillvalue=""):
    x = x.strip()
    y = y.strip()
    print("{0}{1}".format(x, y))
```

Comment: And what is the issue?

Comment: I wanted to print with 2 python scripts on the same line side by side, but I can't do that. This is the closest I can get to that but I want to add time.sleep() to 1 of the text files, not both.

Answer (score 1):

You can print only x (without newline), then sleep and print y.

**Python 2 solution:**

```py
import time
from itertools import izip_longest
import sys

with open("file1") as textfile1, open("file2") as textfile2:
    for x, y in izip_longest(textfile1, textfile2, fillvalue=""):
        x = x.strip()
        sys.stdout.write("{0}".format(x))
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(1)
        y = y.strip()
        sys.stdout.write("{0}".format(y))
        sys.stdout.write("\n")
        sys.stdout.flush()
```

**Python 3 solution**

```py
from itertools import zip_longest
import time

with open("file1") as textfile1, open("file2") as textfile2:
    for x, y in zip_longest(textfile1, textfile2, fillvalue=""):
        x = x.strip()
        print("{0}".format(x), end='')
        time.sleep(1)
        y = y.strip()
        print("{0}".format(y))
```

Comment: This part is causing an error   end='')  SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: and do both of the them print on the same line?

Comment: By default print(x) prints a newline at the end of the string. print(x, end='') is telling python to print nothing at the end of the line, therefore the next print will be on the same line.

Comment: Ah, you're using Python 2? I have written this code in Python 3. I'm updating the answer with Python 2 version

Comment: Yes I'm using Python 2, I was just using it and testing it. Your code is similar to my code I was using. Yours just print file 1 first then the other file proceeds. For your code, Can you add a timer to both files, both files needs their own timer. Every time they both print I should see different combinations everytime, not the same merged lines. That's what I'm overall trying to get the script to do.

Comment: Given file1 has two lines (a,b) and file2 has two lines (c,d) it will print ab in the first line and cd in the second line. What is your expected result in this scenario ?

Comment: It will most likely print the same combinations.

Comment: Unless its going to be after ab has printed, then file 2 print its going to be b,c, then, a,c, and then b,d, and final a,d. Different combinations as they print down.

Comment: is there a way to set a timer and print 1 whole file firstthen the other file print when the first file is done printing?

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you want, but I guess it's something like this

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3

from rx import from_, interval, merge, zip
from rx.scheduler import ThreadPoolScheduler

pool = ThreadPoolScheduler(10)


f1 = from_(open('f1.txt'))
f2 = from_(open('f2.txt'))

o1 = merge(
    f1,
    zip(interval(1.0), f2)
    )

o1.subscribe(print, scheduler=pool)
o1.run()
```

It uses [RxPy](https://rxpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html).
And works like:

1. creates observable for file 1
2. creates observable for file 2
3. creates another observable merging f1 and f2, which is emitted in intervals of 1sec
4. subscribe and print
5. wait until it finishes

Comment: I updated my post and tried to give an better idea when I'm trying to do.

Comment: Is this in bash or python, because I have it in a python script and it says o1.subscribe(print, scheduler=pool) SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Do you have the solution in python 2?

Comment: For Python 2.x you need to use version RxPy 1.6. You may need to adapt the syntax a bit but the logic is the same